# Como puedo determinar el ganador con una regla de 3 rondas?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
from random import randint

def player1():
    return randint(1, 6)

primer_dado = player1()
segundo_dado = player1()

jugador1 = (primer_dado + segundo_dado)

def player2():
    return randint(1, 6)

primer_dado = player2()
segundo_dado = player2()

jugador2 = (primer_dado + segundo_dado)

def obtenidos():
    
    if (jugador1 == jugador2):   
        print("El jugador 1 ha ganado.")
    else:
        print("El jugador 2 ha ganado.")


print(f"Primero jugador: ", jugador1)
print(f"Segundo jugador: ", jugador2)
obtenidos()
```

Comment: Como puedo finalizar el juego cuando alguno de los jugadores gane 3 rondas ?

Comment: gracias @rpaillao

Comment: No entiendo bien cómo se gana una ronda. Si la suma de dados del jugador1 == suma de dados del jugador2, entonces ¿gana jugador1, de lo contrario gana jugador2? Si esto es así, hay una muy alta probabilidad, arriba del 90%, de que siempre gane el jugador2.

Comment: Hola @aeportugal así es, realmente la probabilidad es de case 90%, pero así es el problema que fue presentado. Son dos jugadores, se los valores obtenidos en los dos lanzamientos son IGUALES, el jugador1 gana, si son distintos gana el jugador2. GANA el jugador que gana 3 rondas, puedes ayudarme ? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado no estás usando correctamente la finalidad de las funciones. Las funciones pueden llamarse muchas veces y así reducir el código y disminuir la complejidad.
Sugeriría que la función devuelva los valores de los 2 dados de una sola vez.

```
from random import randint

def tirada():
    return randint(1, 6), randint(1, 6)
```

Ahora en el programa principal hay que tener una variable, para cada jugador, que acumulará la cantidad de veces que ha ganado, `ganadosx`

En un `while`, por cada vuelta se verifica si ambos han ganado menos de 3 veces. En otras palabras, el `while` iterará hasta que uno de los 2 acumuladores llegue a 3 y entonces se cerrará el ciclo.

```
# ####
ganados1 = 0
ganados2 = 0

while ganados1 < 3 and ganados2 < 3:
    jugador1 = tirada()
    suma1 = sum(jugador1)
    jugador2 = tirada()
    suma2 = sum(jugador2)
    print(f'Jugador1 {jugador1} [{suma1}] - [{suma2}] {jugador2} Jugador2', end='')
    if suma1 == suma2:
        ganados1 += 1
        print(' || ganó jugador1')
    else:
        ganados2 += 1
        print(' || ganó jugador2')
```

Ahora se verifica quién ganó y se imprime el resultado:

```
print('----')
ganador = 'Jugador1' if ganados1 > ganados2 else 'Jugador2'
print(f'El ganandor de 3 rondas es: {ganador}')
```

Si juntas todo el código, y lo ejecutas, producirá una salida como esta:

```
Jugador1 (2, 5) [7] - [9] (4, 5) Jugador2 || ganó jugador2
Jugador1 (3, 3) [6] - [4] (3, 1) Jugador2 || ganó jugador2
Jugador1 (3, 6) [9] - [8] (4, 4) Jugador2 || ganó jugador2
----
El ganandor de 3 rondas es: Jugador2
```

### Notas

- Según el algoritmo, hay aproximadamente un 90% de posibilidad de que gane **jugador2** en cada ronda.
- Si consideramos que el ganador del juego es quien gane primero 3 rondas, entonces la probabilidad aumenta a casi 100% de que siempre ganará el jugador2.

Comment: Muchas gracias ayudo muchisimo. aclaro.