# Como encuentro el ganador de las rondas en los lanzamientos de los dados en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como encuentro el ganador si es el jugador1, ganaría así:

*Si en una misma tirada el valor de sus dados que son dos coinciden. Ejemplo: Jugador 1 [ **2 , 2** ]  y Jugador2 [ 3, 4]

*Si en una tirada, algún número de sus dados coinciden con algún número de los dados del jugador 2. Ejemplo: Jugador 1 [ **3** , 1 ]  y Jugador2 [ **3**, 4].

```
from random import randint

def tirada():
    return randint(1, 6), randint(1, 6)

ganados1 = 0    
ganados2 = 0

while ganados1 < 3 and ganados2 < 3:
    jugador1 = tirada()
    suma1 = sum(jugador1)
    jugador2 = tirada()
    suma2 = sum(jugador2)
    print(f'Jugador1 {jugador1} [{suma1}] - [{suma2}] {jugador2} Jugador2', end='')
    if suma1 == suma2:
        ganados1 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 1 ha ganado.')
    else:
        ganados2 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 2 ha ganado.')
    

ganador = 'Jugador1' if ganados1 > ganados2 else 'Jugador2'
print(f'Enhorabuena al ganador que es: {ganador}')
```

Comment: ¿Puedes redactar un poco mejor la frase del inicio? No se entiende qué condición es la que quieres evaluar o cómo se relaciona eso con quién es el ganador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aclarar, la pregunta es complementaria a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/503575/80870).

El bloque `if` / `else` quedaría así:

```
    if suma1 == suma2:
        ganados1 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 1 ha ganado.')
    elif jugador1[0] == jugador1[1]: 
        # Si ambos dados del jugador1 salen iguales
        ganados1 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 1 ha ganado.')
    elif jugador1[0] in jugador2 or jugador1[1] in jugador2: 
        # Si un dado del jugador1 sale en la tirada del jugador2
        ganados1 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 1 ha ganado.')
    else:
        ganados2 += 1
        print(' || El jugador 2 ha ganado.')
```

En la pregunta anterior, la probabilidad de que ganara el jugador 2 era cercana a 100%. Ahora con esta modificación, haciendo una serie de simulaciones de 1000 rondas cada una:

`[Gana_Jugador1, Gana_Jugador2] || [if, elif_1, elif_2, else]`

- 1ra simulación: `[815, 185] || [437, 609, 1625, 1252]`
- 2da simulación: `[807, 193] || [429, 593, 1638, 1262]`
- 3ra simulación: `[799, 201] || [455, 589, 1617, 1258]`
- 4ta simulación: `[822, 178] || [445, 598, 1647, 1245]`
- 5ta simulación: `[835, 165] || [448, 622, 1658, 1172]`

Ahora hay **80%** de probabilidad que gane el jugador1 y la condición que más se cumple es la tercera (41%): que un número de un dado del jugador1, aparezca en los dados del jugador2